# Black to Clear Gradient Disappears when view is scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cagradientlayer

I have a CAGradientLayer with two colors, black and clear. When the view appears, the gradient displays appropriately however as soon as I scroll my CollectionView, the clear section of the gradient disappears.

```
let gradient: CAGradientLayer = {
    let g = CAGradientLayer()
    g.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
    g.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
    g.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    return g
}()
```

Below is the initial behavior.
[image: Initial Behavior]

Below is the behavior after scrolling.
[image: Behavior After Scrolling]

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
I have included some extra code which includes both the setup of the UIView and the addition of the gradient layer.

```
let toolBar: UIView = {
    let n = UIView()
    n.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    n.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    return n
}()

    view.addSubview(s.toolBar)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: s.toolBar)
    s.toolBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    s.toolBar.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    s.toolBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    s.toolBar.layer.insertSublayer(s.gradient, at: 0)
    s.gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 50)
```

Comment: Where are you adding your layer to? The entire collection view?

Comment: @FangmingNing the gradient is added to a UIView whose frame is that of the black bar in the second image.

Comment: Can you post the code of adding that UIView? That will give us a better clue  why your layer is missing

Comment: @FangmingNing I have included that in an edit.

Comment: Yes I know that you added the gradient layer to your view correctly and we can approve that from your first photo. The reason you get this error is because the View is somehow missing, not the gradient layer. I am suspecting that this happens in your collection view delegate methods, where you are setting up each cell. Since the cell are recycled by prototype, you may end up having a cell without the gradient View. Am I making sense for you?

Comment: I have solved the issue. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view was being created at `override func viewWillLayoutSubviews()`
instead of `override func viewDidLoad()` so whenever the view was scrolled another instance of the gradient was created for however many times viewWillLayoutSubviews was called resulting in multiple gradients being overlaid.